# How to build Apache Sling 9

Tags: java, apache, maven, sling

I am trying to build Apache Sling 9 (from the project root; not just the launchpad/builder project but all modules).

Here is what I did:

1. Check out https://github.com/apache/sling (also tried git://git.apache.org/sling.git)
2. cd sling
3. mvn -DskipTests --update-snapshots package (I am using Maven 3.5.0)

Unfortunately, there are two problems I encounter with this:

- I get an error

  [ERROR] Unable to get artifact for Dependency {groupId=org.apache.sling, artifactId=org.apache.sling.launchpad, version=9-SNAPSHOT, type=slingfeature}: Could not find artifact org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.launchpad:txt:slingfeature:9-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots)
- I want to **build the exact revision of sources used in Apache Sling 9** but I don't know which revision that is

Has anybody tried this? Any pointers on how to do this?

[BTW, this used to work before though I cannot remember the exact revision; certainly after Sling 8 though]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build error was fixed in [r1811803](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1811803), thanks for reporting that!

As for the sources that are included in the Sling 9 release, the process is the following:

- enumerate all artifacts contained in the Sling 9 Launchpad. That is easily available from [the slingfeature.txt file deployed on Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/sling/org.apache.sling.launchpad/9/org.apache.sling.launchpad-9-slingfeature.txt)
- for each artifact with the group id `org.apache.sling`, check out the release tag from `https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/tags/${artifactId}`
- Run a `mvn install` for each of those artifacts

Comment: Thanks Robert. I will try this out today/tomorrow.